# Is it feasible to keep millions of keys in state of Spark Streaming job for two months?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to solve a (simplified here) problem in Spark Streaming: Let's say I have a log of events made by users, where each event is a tuple (user name, activity, time), e.g.:

```
("user1", "view", "2015-04-14T21:04Z")
("user1", "click", "2015-04-14T21:05Z")
```

Now I would like to gather events by user to do some analysis of that. Let's say that output is some analysis of:

```
("user1", List(("view", "2015-04-14T21:04Z"),("click", "2015-04-14T21:05Z"))
```

The events should be kept for even **2 months**. During that time there might be around **500 milion** of such events, and **millions of unique** users, which are keys here.

**My questions are:**

- Is it feasible to do such a thing with `updateStateByKey` on DStream, when I have millions of keys stored?
- Am I right that `DStream.window` is no use here, when I have 2 months length window and would like to have a slide of few seconds?

P.S. 
I found out, that `updateStateByKey` is called on all the keys on every slide, so that means it will be called millions of time every few seconds. That makes me doubt in this design and I'm rather thinking about alternative solutions like:

- using Cassandra for state
- using Trident state (with Cassandra probably)
- using Samza with its state management.

Comment: I have a very exact question about this, just do a quick research and got some points 1) spark improve his way on updating state https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-spark-streaming.html 2) looks like it fit your use case more if you use samza  https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.10/comparisons/spark-streaming.html Anyway, how you implement it? since the question is quite old, I assume you end up with a solution

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you query the data in the future. I have the similar scenarios. I just made the transformation through mapPartitions and reduceByKey and store the data in Cassandra.

Comment: Can you please provide some code or links to documentation to support your answer?

Comment: KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
    ssc,
    Map("auto.offset.reset" -> "largest",
      "auto.commit.enable" -> "false",
      "metadata.broker.list"->"??"
    ),
    Set("??")
  ).mapPartitions(partition => {
    partition.map(tuple => {
      // your transformation

    })
  }).reduceByKey((value1, value2) => {

    // allocate a timestamp to the data and store them to C*
  })
  
  when querying the data, you can search by a range of timestamps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an *exponentially decaying window*.

You can read about them in [Rajaraman, Anand, and Jeffrey David Ullman. Mining of massive datasets. Cambridge University Press, 2011.](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf), check section 4.7 and specially section 4.7.3 for the implementation details.